# ...when construction of the permanent facilities "is" or "are" projected to be complete: which is correct?

Tags: grammatical-number, american-english

> The funding need will extend through the year 2020 when construction of the permanent facilities **is** projected to be complete.

My boss insists I should use **are** instead of **is**. I disagree. Any recommendations?

Comment: You should add any research you’ve done. Or have you tried asking on ELL?

Comment: ". . .when construction **is** complete". 'construction' is the (singular) subject of the verb.

Comment: When your boss are right your boss are right.

Answer (score 1):

I think 'is' refers to 'construction'

and

'are' refers to 'the permanent facilities'.

So you're both right!

Try with just one term:

When construction is projected to be complete.

When the permanent facilities are projected to be complete.

Perhaps your boss is focusing on 'the work to be done' - construction and you are focusing on 'the end result' permanent facilities.

I think you can use either - one carries the sense that we are talking about construction, and the other, permanent facilities.

Thank your boss for his/her helpful input and safeguard your future promotion by not getting into an argument with your boss about 'who is right'!